# xCode 4.3 Unable to read snapshots

Tags: xcode

I am getting this error from xCode "Unable to read snapshots" when trying to retore a snapshot. This happened after restoring a prior snapshot. Also when I restored that snapshot it got mixed up with the current project, buggering everything up..Now im sitting with a broken project.

Where can I locate the snapshot files or is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried any of this, but this answer points out how you can go about recovering snapshots:  [Xcode snapshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359097/xcode-snapshots)